# mod_rewrite parameter as directory and maintain relative url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following php file:

```
http://example.com/details.php?item=asdf
```

However, I would like the url to be more concise:

```
http://example.com/item/asdf/details
```

I tried using the the `.htaccess` file like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^item/(\w+)/details$ details.php?item=$1
```

And the url rewrite works.

However, when I try to load `main.css` which resides at `http://example.com` from `details.php`, I get the following message from Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

since it couldn't find `http://example.com/asdf/main.css`.

Is there any way to use the original url's "base" or "root" directory with the rewritten url? I would like to access `main.css` from a dynamically generated `asdf` "directory". I don't want to use the `base` tag in html because that seems rather messy, or a point to the parent directory since I'm using a template page.

I've tried `RewriteBase /` but that just creates another error. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go the `<base>` route, but instead of hard coding the url, I used php:

```
<base href="/<?=$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below if file not exists it will rewrite if exists it should work as default.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /item/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^item/(\w+)/details$ details.php?item=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've already tried that too. Still get a 404 error since I'm using the "item" subdirectory and my file is located in the main directory

Comment: I found a workaround. +1 because this answer could be useful for someone else.